# How do I get class of an internal static class in another assembly?

Tags: .net, reflection

I have a class C in Assembly A like this:

```
internal class C
{
  internal static string About_Name {
      get { return "text"; }
  ...
}
```

I have about 20 such static properties. Is there a way, in an outside assembly, without using friend assembly attribute (.Net reflection only), get class C so I can invoke any of the static string properties like this:

```
Class C = <some .Net reflection code>;
string expected = C.About_Name;
```

If that is not possible, a .Net reflection code to get the string property value directly will suffice, but not ideal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this...
**Edit:** I did not think about just using the type instead of object instance when it was a static property. 
**Removed** `var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);` and use `type` in prop.GetValue instead of `obj`.

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    internal class Class1
    {
        internal static string Test { get { return "test"; } }
    }
    public class Class2
    {

    }
}

var ass = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Class2));
var type = ass.GetType("ClassLibrary1.Class1");
var prop = type.GetProperty("Test", BindingFlags.Static 
    | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var s = (string)prop.GetValue(type, null);
```

Comment: Well, thats pretty much the same as my answer, but remember he's reflecting a static property, so there is no need to instantiate it using `Activator` before getting the value.

Comment: @Kyle Rozendo, you are right about creating the object. The difference is in getting the type.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it can be done.

It's using `Type.GetProperty()`.

Example:

```
// Load your assembly and Get the Type
// Assembly load code...
...
// Get type
Type asmType = typeof(C);

// Get internal properties
PropertyInfo pi = asmType.GetProperty("About_Name", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

// Get Value
var val = pi.GetValue(asmType, null);
```

This code will return "`text`" in `val`, so from there do what you need to with it.

To do this in the sense that you want to, make the code into a method as follows:

```
    private static string GetString(Type classToCheck, string PropertyName)
    {
        PropertyInfo pi = classToCheck.GetProperty(PropertyName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

        object val = null;

        if (pi != null)
            val = pi.GetValue(classToCheck, null);

        return (val != null) ? val.ToString() : string.Empty;
    }
```

The usage will then be:

```
string expected = GetString(typeof(C), "About_Name");
```

Comment: The class itself is internal, so typeof(C) doesn't compile. How do you get Type of a class if you can't reference it in an outside assembly?

Comment: @Ech - Have you tried reflecting the classes in the same way I did the methods above, using the correct `BindingFlags`?

Comment: `typeof(C)` not valid if is ***internal static class*** ?